# Using env() css variables with styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Are `env` variables supported in styled-components? I was trying to utilise inset ones to style around iPhone's notch, but the following doesn't work, nor does it fall back to those 40px

```js
const Header = styled.header`
  padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top, 40px);
`;
```

normal `padding-top: 40px;` works as expected.

I tested this in chrome browser on my desktop and safari on my iPhone X, the result is no padding at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styled Components does support it, this must be something else.

Perhaps your iOS version doesn't support `env()`?

Try using `constant()` as a fallback too:

```
body {
  /* No variables */
  padding-top: 12px;

  /* iOS Safari 11.2, Safari 11 */
  padding-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top, 12px); 

  /* iOS Safari 11.4+, Safari 11.1+, Chrome 69+, Opera 56+ */
  padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top, 12px); 
}
```